# How to create a connection with MySQL Admin?

Tags: mysql, connection, admin

I am extremly new with databases. I have only created one, and that was in SQLite on android. I downloaded MySQL Admin for linux (Ubuntu) and downloaded and installed Admin. Now I want to create a database, but I jave know idea what I'm doing. I created a connection via the drop down menu option 'Open Connection Editor', and I keep getting a 'MySQL Error Nr. 2005' error. Do I have to do something command line wise first to set up the database?

Any help is appreciated.

Aedon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is different to SQLite in that you need to have some server software running the whole time managing the database. It's that server software that you connect a MySQL client to.

You need to grab yourself a copy of MySQL Server then I'd recommend [this tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html)

Good luck!

Comment: Could I write a simple java server and connect the database to that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu you can install MySQL Server easily with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

and then I suggest you to download **MySQL Workbench**, it's a GUI Tool where you can do almost everything with **MySQL databases** (create,drop,alter, modeling, administer the service).

Then, you can create a connection with **mysql workbench** or **mysql admin (or another client)** and do your stuff. If you installed the server in your PC then the parameter are something like this:

```
host = localhost
user = root
password = (the password you specified in the installation)
```